# Clickable row in table, with row values returned as dictionary

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to return the values of a table row as a dictionary (preferably with the column names as keys). However, my attempts only achieve a concatenated string of all values.
In my working example I return:

> 123

However, what I would like to achieve is something like this:

> {"col1": 1, "col2": 2, "col3": 3}

.

Example code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable-row').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('*').text();
    console.log(row);
    return false
  });
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="clickable-row" class="clickable-row" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get JSON output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable-row').click(function() {
    var column_names = $("thead").find("th");
    var row = $(this).find("td").toArray().reduce(function(previous, current_node, index) {
      var text = $(column_names[index]).text();
      previous[text] = $(current_node).text();
      return previous; 
    }, {});
    console.log(row);
    return false
  });
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="clickable-row" class="clickable-row" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```